# Using SMIE for language without comment syntax

Tags: syntax, smie

I'm making a major mode for json (which has no comments), and using SMIE for 'free' indenting.

I've currently got a half-baked grammar called `json-grammar`, and no `rules-function`.

Consequently, I'm invoking `smie-setup` as

```
(smie-setup json-grammar (lambda (method arg) ()))
```

However, in a few places I'm calling `smie-indent-line`, and when I do, `smie-indent-line` eventually calls `comment-normalize-vars`

This function asks for a value `comment syntax`, and insists on having some value. Given that I want to use `SMIE` for indentation, how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Would hacking together a regexp that will never match anything work? (Maybe `$;` will do)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use dummy comment settings.  E.g. `"#"` for `comment-start` and `` "\\`.\\`" `` for `comment-start-skip`.